# There is no header still session_start() sending it

Tags: php, session

[image]I checked topics related session_start(); sry couldnt find what can help me

```
  session_start();
  include "databaseregistration.php";
  include "check_function.php";
  session_check();
```

check_function.php contain (simplified code to check where i went wrong)

```
   <?php
   function session_check(){
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_title'])){
echo "error";
    }
    else{
    echo "pass";
    }
    }?>
```

now error i am getting is

```
 Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at F:\xampp\htdocs\ourwork\proper pages\homef.php:1) in F:\xampp\htdocs\ourwork\proper pages\homef.php on line 2
```

you can see i am not sending any header yet and whenever i am removing session_start(); warning is gone

why it is sending header when it is not in code ......Need help struck here :(

Comment: there is a tab before the opening `<?php` tag from what I can see in your code - and that alone is sending headers to the browser already

Comment: To avoid this kind of errors, it's good practice to not write ?> closing tags at the end of a file.

Comment: There must be something before the session start.  Even if there's no executable code, any whitespace prior to the opening <?php will trigger the headers to be sent, even invisible characters like whitespace, or even the UTF BOM if it's set.  Make sure that the absolute first 5 characters in your file are <?php and that the same is true of any and all files that get included as well.

Comment: try to add ob_start(); to top

Comment: i now removed include "check_function.php"; but still it is showing error

Comment: what should b UTF BOM?

Comment: @Maria Google UTF BOM and become enlightened :)

Comment: @GordonM can you please explain a bit about absolute first 5 characters in your file are <?php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankx to GordonM and Oswald i checked the "encoding "in my notepad++ and change the encoding to UTF without BOM and it solved my problem:)

Answer (score 1):

*Every* output will send headers to the browser. Output can be pretty much everything, *including whitespace*. The most common mistake is that you have a space, newline, or tab before the php open tag (`<?php`). Please make sure `session_start()` is called before anything is sent to the browser.

The `session_start()` function will add info to the headers, to store a cookie in the users browser. In the cookie the session id is stored, to retrieve the info needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's something outputting something in line 1 of `F:\xampp\htdocs\ourwork\proper pages\homef.php`.

Note that whitespace and byte order marks before the opening `<?php` are also considered output.

Comment: on line 1 is session_start();

Comment: Then on which line is the `<?php` that is required by the PHP interpreter to interpret the following code as PHP? If your code is not inside `<?php` and `?>`, then the PHP interpreter regards it as output and sends it straight to `stdout` unprocessed.

Comment: According to the error message, you have *session_start() ... in F:\xampp\htdocs\ourwork\proper pages\homef.php on line 2*, not in line 1.

Comment: u r right on first line it is <?php check i uploaded page pic

Comment: I suspect there is a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) before the `<?php`. Byte order marks are invisible. Tell the editor not to include a byte order mark or use a hex editor to remove it.

Comment: Thankx Solved i only went in notepad++ encoding and checked UTF without BOM its solved my problem Thank Oswald and GordonM cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the final `?>` from the `check_function.php` file. It's not required and you can inadvertently have a space or a newline after it

PHP will interpret an end of file as a closing `?>` if there is an enclosed `<?php`